# DatagramSocket Receive method doesnt receive any packet in UPnP / DLNA discovery on android TV

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, wifi, upnp

```
companion object {
    private const val DISCOVER_TIMEOUT = 1500
    private const val LINE_END = "\r\n"
    private const val DEFAULT_QUERY = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1" + LINE_END +
            "HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900" + LINE_END +
            "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"" + LINE_END +
            "MX: 1" + LINE_END +  //"ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1" + LINE_END + // Use for Sonos
            "ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1" + LINE_END + // Use for Routes
            LINE_END
    private const val DEFAULT_ADDRESS = "239.255.255.250"}


suspend fun startUPnPDiscovery() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val wifi =
            context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        if (wifi != null) {
            val lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylock")
            lock.acquire()
            var socket: DatagramSocket? = null
            try {
                val group = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250")
                val port = 1900
                val query = customQuery
                socket = DatagramSocket(null)
                socket.reuseAddress = true
                socket.broadcast = true
                socket.bind(InetSocketAddress(port))
                val datagramPacketRequest =
                    DatagramPacket(query.toByteArray(), query.length, group, port)
                socket.send(datagramPacketRequest)
                while (true) {
                    val datagramPacket = DatagramPacket(ByteArray(1024), 1024)
                    socket.receive(datagramPacket)
                    val response = String(datagramPacket.data, 0, datagramPacket.length)
                    if (response.substring(0, 12).toUpperCase() == "HTTP/1.1 200") {
                        val device = UPnPDevice(datagramPacket.address.hostAddress, response)
                        threadCount++
                        getData(device.location, device)
                        break
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                listener?.onError(e)
            } finally {
                socket?.close()
            }
            lock.release()
        }
    }
}
```

Hi I am trying to discover Router using Android TV. The above piece of code is working fine with Android Mobiles and I am able to fetch router details but when run on Android TV I never receive any packet. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a fuller code snippet?  Without definitions for `internetAddress`, `port` and `query` its impossible to see whether you are forming a valid SSDP query

Comment: @simonc I have updated the question with details, can you please suggest why android tv is not able to receive packets?

Comment: Your UPnP query looks good.  Before looking through your code further, it might be worth double checking that your router supports UPnP discovery (e.g. by using a universal control point)

Comment: Yes Router supports UPnP and the same piece of code works perfectly fine on Android Mobile devices, its just not working on Android TV. on Android Mobiles I am getting desired outputs but not on Android TV. Any further suggestions please @simonc ?